# On all new project error ContextWrapper not found comes but when i change target and compileSdkVersion to 30 it works fine then why happens with sdk31

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

It is happening to every project I am creating , I tried everything -
Invalidate cache & restart , Re-Build , Clean Project , but it didn't worked

Every time it shows -

```
Cannot access 'android.content.ContextWrapper' which is a super type of com.example.projectname.MainActivity  . Check your module classpath for missing or conflict dependencies .
```

[Error it shows every where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYz1w.png)

[This is my Gradle File when it shows error .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbubT.png)

Answer (score 0):

**This actually happens if Sdk 31 or the Sdk version with you are getting error is missing some files** , the solution worked for me is :-

Go to ,
*C:\Users\india\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk*

and from platforms & platform-tools folder delete folder android-31 or Sdk version you are getting error with ,

After this open Android Studio and from :-
*File>Settings>Android Sdk*

Install SDK Platform 31 or Platform you are getting errors , also on SDK Platform Tools tab install respective tools of platform you installed .
[SDK Platform like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ12A.png) and [SDK Platform Tools like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWdlI.png)

Then -
Clean your project **-->** Sync Gradle **-->** Re-Build Project .

That's it after this error is Gone !